# Error in authenticate a websocket with token authentication on django channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

I face an error when calling the websocket url with passing a JWT token for authentication purpose:

my websocket request is:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/chat_2/?token=
```

the error is:

raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'chat/chat_2/'.

I'm using a custom authentication middleware:

**middleware.py**

```
"""
General web socket middlewares
"""

from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken, TokenError
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import UntypedToken
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTTokenUserAuthentication
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.db import close_old_connections
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from jwt import decode as jwt_decode
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(validated_token):
    try:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=validated_token["user_id"])
        print(f"{user}")
        return user

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()


class JwtAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Close old database connections to prevent usage of timed out connections
        close_old_connections()

        # Get the token
        token = parse_qs(scope["query_string"].decode("utf8"))["token"][0]

        # Try to authenticate the user
        try:
            # This will automatically validate the token and raise an error if token is invalid
            UntypedToken(token)
        except (InvalidToken, TokenError) as e:
            # Token is invalid
            print(e)
            return None
        else:
            #  Then token is valid, decode it
            decoded_data = jwt_decode(
                token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"]
            )
            print(decoded_data)
            # Get the user using ID
            scope["user"] = await get_user(validated_token=decoded_data)
        return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)


def JwtAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
    return JwtAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

**routing.py:**

```
from . import consumers
from django.urls.conf import path

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/chat/<str:room_name>/", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path(
        "ws/personal_chat/<str:room_name>/",
        consumers.PersonalConsumer.as_asgi(),
    ),
]
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
import ChatApp.routing
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()  
from ChatApp.middlewares import JwtAuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Hookax.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": JwtAuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(ChatApp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        ),
    }
)
```

The project based on:

```
Django 3.2.7 
Channels 3.0.4
```

Any suggestions solution?